# Why is eslint throwing error for .d.ts files in my node project

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint

I have configured eslint for my typescript node project. There is also a file `app.d.ts` in the repo. On running the lint, I get the following error

```
 error  Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: src/app.d.ts.
The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided
```

I have already tried creating `tsconfig.eslint.json` and its contents are as follows

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": [ "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.unit.test.ts", "jest.config.js", "__tests__/**/*.int.test.ts"],
}
```

And in the `.eslintrc.js`, I added the parser option

```
parserOptions: {
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: './tsconfig.eslint.json',
    tsconfigRootDir: './',
  },
```

But Im still getting this error. What am I missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Does the name of your declaration file shadow a typescript file of the same name?

If so you will get this error. Declaration files are for providing types for javascript files so there isn't the need to provide one for a file written in typescript.